# Conflict between Shadowbox and a jQuery div fader

Tags: jquery, html, conflict, shadowbox

I'm using a jQuery script which fades in/out my divs so I can have one single page for my website. I'm also using Shadowbox script to display my images in a gallery.

The problem is that when I click on a thumbnail (which opens Shadowbox and my image), it cleans the content of my div out. So I end up with a blank page.

Here's my fader script:

```
  document.documentElement.className += " js";   
  $(function(){
    var $containers = $("#right > div").hide();
    $containers.eq(0).show();

    $('a').each(function(i,el){
      var idx = i;
      $(this).click(function(e){
        var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
        if($containers.filter(':visible').not($target).length){
          $containers.filter(':visible').fadeOut(400, function(){
            $target.not(':visible').fadeIn(400);
          });
        } else {
          $target.not(':visible').fadeIn(400);
        }

      })
    })
  });
```

So that's the job of this script to replace div content, but is it possible to make an exception for the shadowbox script when I launch it?

The working files are here: http://www.hyker.be/minimal

And the scripts (shadowbox and fader): http://www.hyker.be/minimal/js/misc.js

Comment: can you make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can see the interaction with the HTML

Comment: Hey, I didn't succeed in setting up a working jsfiddle example, so I uploaded the files on my ftp:

[link](http://www.hyker.be/minimal/) 

You can access the scripts here (shadow box and fader):

[link](http://www.hyker.be/minimal/js/misc.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the click code is also working with gallery links as well. To exclude gallery anchor tags from your current click code use **[not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** method or selector in jquery.

In your case the code should be :

```
$('a').not("a[rel*=shadowbox]").each(function(i,el){
    //existing stuff
})
```

or

```
$('a:not(a[rel*=shadowbox])').each(function(i,el){
    //existing stuff
})
```

Good Luck !!